# Is there a workaround for nested selects in Bazel build?

Tags: bazel

I have a Bazel build file that selects what files and defines to include in my library based on 2 possible backends (A and B). I use select to do this, but I also want a default behavior to let another variable set them (for example, platform). Since this would require nested selects, I can workaround it by having an intermediate filegroup target for the default behavior (platform based). But I'm not sure what to do about the defines which are just a list of strings. This is an example of how I configured the BUILD file:

```
filegroup(
    name = "_backend_based_on_platform_srcs",
    srcs = select({
        "//darwin": _backend_a_srcs,
        "//linux": _backend_b_srcs,
    })  
)

filegroup(
    name = "headers",
    srcs = glob([
        "include/common/*.hpp",
    ]) + select({
        "//backend_a": _backend_a_srcs,
        "//backend_b": _backend_b_srcs,
        "//backend_default": [":_backend_based_on_platform_srcs"],
    }),
)

cc_library(
    name = "custom_lib",
    hdrs = [
        ":headers",
    ],
    defines = select({
        "//backend_a": _backend_a_defines,
        "//backend_b": _backend_b_defines,
        #"//backend_default": [":_backend_based_on_platform_defines"],
        }),
    includes = ["include"],
    strip_include_prefix = "include",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

I'd like to have an intermediate target for the defines so that I can put a select in it, but I don't know if that exists. I tried using alias, but that can only take a string and not a list of strings (multiple define constants). Is there something else I can try to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried [config_setting](https://bazel.build/docs/configurable-attributes)

Comment: Kind of? I ended up using config_setting_group and match_all. Basically, I created a config setting for each individual platform AND (match_all) backend_default. Then, for cc_library, I used selects.with_or to match the backend and platform based conditions to the defines I have. I'll answer my own question if no one proposes a better solution.